# CodeIgniter: Excel file upload Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload excel file in CodeIgniter  as i have specified below but it says invalid file. Is there a hidden issue with CodeIgniter or with my filetype specification?

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
```

Comment: What is the exact name of your file?

Comment: The file name varies, it can be abc.xlsx, or cds.xlsx

Comment: Review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495407/uploading-in-codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allo

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my mime.php:

```
'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword'),
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword'),
```

Don't forget about 'application/vnd.ms-office'.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your mimes.php also check your excel extention name

or you can use also

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';

'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip')
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found this solution

'xlsx' =>       array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword'),

'xls'   =>      array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/octet-stream'),

Answer (score 0):

Other solution by joni jones [Uploading in Codeigniter - The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495407/uploading-in-codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allo)

If you don't want to change system files. Just try this:

Open `system/libraries/Upload.php` (method `do_upload()` line 205) and do this:

```
var_dump($this->file_type);
exit();
```

Try to upload some file. Add file type, which you see in `var_dump()` to `application/config/mimes.php`.  Little example: you have problem with .docx. Try to add:

```
'docx' => array('application/zip', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
```

to `application/config/mimes.php`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'xls' => array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/octet-stream'),

'xlsx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword'),
'xls' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'applica
    tion/msword'),
```

repalce with your previous mime type of xls and xlsx put the above code it can be work

xls two add not a problem

```
'xls' => array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/octet-stream'), working in to the my local but not working this live sit(Production site)

'xls' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'applica
        tion/msword'),
```

it is working on the live production site

i am placing two xls it both places working

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problems with CodeIgniter File Upploads and my version of CodeIgniter is currently 2.2.0
You can find an answer looking at my following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528343/1752988)!!!

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

In **`config/mimes.php`**

add this

```
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel'),
'ods'   =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip')
```

---

and in **your configuration**

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|xls|ods';
```