# MIME type XLSX (from LibreOffice)

Tags: php, excel, file-upload, mime-types, libreoffice

I'm trying to solve one problem: I want to upload to my website XLS/XLSX file. And I've there for it this condition:

```
if((mime_content_type($file) == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' || mime_content_type($file) == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') && ($extension == 'xls' || $extension == 'XLS' || $extension == 'xlsx' || $extension == 'XLSX')){...upload...}
```

When I use the XLS/X file (which has been saved directly from MS Excel), it works great. But when I want to upload XLS/X file - which has been saved directly from LibreOffice (not as ODS, but as an XLS/X) - it doesn't work and I can't upload this file.

Thanks for any help!

(And the condition with *application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet* doesn't work as well.)

**Update: Thanks to Dipanwita Kundu I was able to find, which MIME type is used** (`application/octet-stream`) - **but its safe to put this as the condition?**

Comment: Try to use `'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'

Comment: Hi, thanks - but without any effect, it's still not working.

Comment: try to print your mime content type I mean echo `mime_content_type($file)` & check the result.

Comment: Great idea :) It prints: `application/octet-stream` - but its safe to put this as the condition?

Comment: As you are checking `mime_content_type` & allowing file based on mime type, so it has the same risk like other mime type

Comment: Thank you - really very much!

Comment: Fun fact: LibreOffice 5.4.2.2.0+ doesn't save as `application/octet-stream` any more.  Now it's `application/zip` because someone thought that made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if((mime_content_type($file) == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' || mime_content_type($file) == 'application/vnd.ms-excel' || mime_content_type($file) == 'application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet') && ($extension == 'xls' || $extension == 'XLS' || $extension == 'xlsx' || $extension == 'XLSX')){...upload...}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort :) But it's not working :( (And before that it didn't write me any error (just 'my' message, that its not supported file), now with your solution its writing me: 'Warning: mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments in /data/web/virtuals/25/virtual/www/subdom/avcr/vrstvy/upload.php on line 124'.

Answer (score 0):

If you save an file with LibreOffice Calc, then the php mime_content_type($file) return value is 'application/zip'.

[Upload xls or xlsx files with codeigniter, mime-type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166892/upload-xls-or-xlsx-files-with-codeigniter-mime-type-error)