# codeingitor how to allow .bmp file to upload?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to allow .bmp file format to upload

Here is my code:

```
            $config = [];
            $config['file_name'] = $filename;
            $config['upload_path'] = $dir;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|pdf';
            $config['max_size'] = '10000';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);               
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
```

but error like **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed**.

Comment: check in `config/mimes.php`, if you found `bmp` then it should work

Comment: yes there found my file

Comment: which PHP version ?

Comment: PHP Version 7.4.11

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9876789/6309457

Comment: Yes i already do that, but not working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
$mimes = array('bmp' => array('image/bmp', 'image/x-windows-bmp', 'image/x-ms-bmp'))
```

in application/config/mimes.php