# How to upload image via CURL to Codeigniter REST API

Tags: codeigniter, rest, curl

I'm using a REST API in Codeigniter and trying to set up an image upload method. I've managed to upload fine using a multipart form but get a file type error using the REST client below. I think the problem is "file_type" is showing as "application/octet-stream".

(Codeigniter Upload: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

REST Method

```
function do_upload_post()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './savefiles/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload() )
    {
        print_r($this->upload->display_errors('', ''));
        print_r($this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

REST Client

```
function curl_upload(){
    $url = 'http://localhost/api/file/do_upload';
    $file = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ds_site\designs\pics\file.jpg';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $post = array(
        "userfile" => "@$file"
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Output

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
Array
(
    [file_name] => aliens.jpg
    [file_type] => application/octet-stream
    [file_path] => C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ds_site/savefiles/
    [full_path] => C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ds_site/savefiles/aliens.jpg
    [raw_name] => aliens
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => aliens.jpg
    [file_ext] => .jpg
    [file_size] => 103745
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

Comment: Did you check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495407/uploading-in-codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allo ?

Comment: I hadn't see it actually. I've not tested the suggestions they discusa but the problems discussed are general upload file type issues and not specifically using cURL and I have managed to upload fine using a multipart/form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I needed to define the file type.

```
"userfile" => "@$file;type=image/jpeg"
```