# PDF upload not working but other extensions works

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a program that used to accept image from user. I changed it to accept PDF file instead as requested by our clients problem is it doesn't work.

I already changed my mimes.php configuration to this

```
'pdf'    =>    array('application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/x-download','application/download','binary/octet-stream'),
```

Here is my CI code for saving uploaded file

```
$config = array(
'upload_path'   =>  'news',
'allowed_types' =>  'pdf',
'max_size'  =>  '10000000',
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
$data = $this->upload->data();
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

HTML

```
<form id="imgadd-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Upload :<br>
   <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
function uploadfile()
{
$.ajaxFileUpload({
    url     :   'save_data/uploadfile/',
    secureuri   :   false ,
    fileElementId   :   'userfile' ,
    dataType    :   'json' ,
    success     :   function( data , status ) {
        if ( status != 'error' ){//&& data.data.is_image ) {
            sysAlert( 'File Successfully Uploaded' );
        }
        else
            sysAlert( 'Error Uploading' );
    }
});
}
```

EDIT:
The file is being reported by jquery as uploaded successfully since it returns the JSON but whenever I check the directory, nothing is there.
Weird thing though, I renamed the file extension to .TXT and uploaded that 3.5MB pdf file with a .txt extension and it uploaded successfully and is in the proper directory.

EDIT:
var_dump of $_FILES

```
"array(1) {
  ["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=> string(8) "test.pdf"
    ["type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    ["tmp_name"]=>string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF84F.tmp"
    ["error"]=>int(0)
    ["size"]=>int(3748991)
  }
}
```

echo $this->upload->display_errors();

```
<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>
```

Update:
Change 'max_size'

```
'max_size'      =>  '10000000',
```

**CI Version is 2.1.2**

Comment: are you sure you set enough `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`?

Comment: @Serg I checked the phpinfo(); `upload_max_filesize 128M` and `post_max_size 8M`

Comment: Could you check the $_FILE variable make a var_dump and see its content, maybe you can find something missing !

Comment: After `do_upload` give `echo $this->upload->display_errors();` and see if you are getting any error message.

Comment: @Madev Added the var_dump of $_FILES in my post

Comment: @air4x I get this message *<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.</p>*

Comment: looking in your dump: I see the actual size of the file is: 3748991 which is bigger than the specified max size set to be only: 90000

Comment: @Madev changed 'max_size' to '10000000', still doesn't work

Comment: hum... there is a comma at the end of this line: 'max_size'      =>  '10000000',
remove it and check again

Comment: also, which version of CI you are using ?

Comment: possibly here you find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495407/uploading-in-codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allo

Comment: ('CI_VERSION', '2.1.2');

Comment: as Serg mentioned you may have to check the thread

Comment: also try to add application/octet-stream to the array

'pdf'    =>    array('application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/x-download','application/download','binary/octet-stream'),


in mimes.php

Comment: @Madev That did IT!!! Thanks. You might as well post your comment in the answer section so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm happy it helped you, welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

Mimes.php

```
'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/x-download')
```

CI Code:

```
$config['upload_path']   = '$path'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';   
                $config['max_size']      = '4096';      
                $config['overwrite']     =  TRUE;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->display_errors('', '');

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("csv_file")) {
                      echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die();
                      $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                } else {
                    $upload_result = $this->upload->data(); 
                }
```

Comment: it is weird that only firefox think pdf files are format 'application/x-download'