# Getting "filetype not allowed" with Codeigniter upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, mime-types

First of all, there are already a lot of (solved) questions regarding this topic. And I tried all possible solutions. But to no avail.

- The problem occurs in both CI versions `2.1.4` and `2.2.1`.
- I also tried using different filetypes, such as `png`,`gif` and `txt`.
- I've done no `mime-type` alterations, eg. by using `AddType` in the `.htaccess` file
- I've used a simple html form, and a [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) for debugging
- I've tried it with both PHP versions `5.5` and `5.6` (fileinfo module enabled)
- The mime types do exist in the `mimes.php` file
- The `tmp` folder is writable

I'm out of options...
Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Thanks in advance!

---

#### configuration

```php
$this->uploadconfig =  array(
    'upload_path'     => "./tmp/",
    'allowed_types'   => "png|gif|txt",
    'overwrite'       => TRUE,
    'max_size'        => "25000KB",
    'max_height'      => "5000",
    'max_width'       => "5000"
);
$this->load->library('upload', $this->uploadconfig);
```

#### error

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

#### output

```php
[file_name] => test.png
[file_type] => image/png
[file_path] => /CORRECT_SERVER_PATH/tmp/
[full_path] => /CORRECT_SERVER_PATH/tmp/test.png
[raw_name] => test
[orig_name] => 
[client_name] => test.png
[file_ext] => .png
[file_size] => 851
[is_image] => 1
[image_width] => 
[image_height] => 
[image_type] => 
[image_size_str] =>
```

Comment: Do you have 

'gif' => 'image/gif',

'png' => 'image/png',

defined in your min file?

Comment: Yes, in this form: `'png' => array('image/png',  'image/x-png')`

Comment: May this help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815208/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed

Comment: @Ts's Checking the mime types made me find the problem. Thanks for looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Codeigniter `2.1.4` has a bug as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495407/uploading-in-codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allo).
So I've update CI to version `2.2.1`, folowing the update instrucions [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_220.html) and [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_221.html).

After checking the `mimes.php` file for a second time, I noticed a **difference** between my original file, and the one included in the newer version. I replaced the old one with the newer one, and the problem was solved.

Not documented in the upgrade instructions, is the fact that there is a difference between both files. The older (`CI 2.1.4`) of the file returns an array. The newer one (`CI 2.2.1`) does not return an array, but sets an array with the variable name `$mimes`.