# Codeigniter 2 File Upload Not Working / Possible Folder Permission Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to upload a file on CodeIgniter 2 but it fails. I tried a few different ways, actually CI is getting the file and trying to put it in destination folder but I think there is a problem with folder permissions. Because I can echo file name etc.

This is my model file's related part:

```
$config =   array
    (
    'upload_path'       =>  'uploads/campaigns/data',
    'allowed_types'     =>  'csv',
    );
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('file');

    $file       =   $this->upload->data();
    $file_name  =   $file['file_name'];

    if(!empty($file_name)) {

        echo $file_name;
    }
    else {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
```

With this code, I can see filename but file is not uploading. I only have root account on this server and all files created and owned by root. Folders have 777 permission. What should I try now?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to track your errors

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}
```

I hope you loaded the library as well

**EDIT 01**

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/campaigns/data';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$config['max_size'] = '5120'; # 5MB allowd

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
    echo $this->upload->data();
}
```

And in `application/config/mimes.php`

Check there is a `csv` format. If ot exist add this on array  as new item

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel'),
```

Comment: Of course I loaded library, I can get file details please read well. Thank you.

Comment: @DenizB. add this. Then this will show whats wrong. then post error message here. Will give solution ;)

Comment: I already added this, please check my code. I said "If I can not get file name, echo display errors" and file name returning me. So, CI thinks there is no error.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It says: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. But I'm allowing .csv files.

Comment: @DenizB. and add if like this **`if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())`**

Comment: OK but I already allowed .csv file, how can I fix it do you have any idea?

Comment: It's same. Not uploading.

Comment: whats the error and check file format that you trying to upload

Comment: I'm trying to upload .csv, I'm sure that. I think there is a problem with permission thing, I'm still getting "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed" error.

Comment: No. if perpition it shows permition error. did you check in this ?? **`application/config/mimes.php`**

Comment: Yes, I checked it and made the change you said.

Comment: If there not csv then add

Comment: Probably there is another bug. I'm making my search over web now. Thank you.

Comment: @DenizB. ah ok ok. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with Upload library of the Codeigniter. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495407/uploading-in-codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allo) for more details and I hope this will help you.